# select if field match or if child record field match

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table Cities as

```
(Id, Name, ParentId)
```

where ParentId is the Id of a City (self related table)

I want to get the cities wheres the parentId is null (root)
if the name matches or child record name matches I wrote this

```
declare @cities table (Id, Name, ParentId)

insert into @cities (Id , Name) 
select Id , Name from Cities
Where CHARINDEX(N'CD', Name) > 0 and ParentId is null 

insert into @cities (Id , Name) 
select Id , Name from Cities
Where Id in 
   (select distinct ParentId from Cities 
    where CHARINDEX(N'CD', Name) > 0 ParentId is not null) 
and ParentId is null 

select distinct * from @cities
```

What can I do to make it faster and better?
Edit:

```
Id  | Name  | ParentId 
----------------------
1   | ABCD  | NULL
----------------------
2   | EFZX  | NULL
----------------------
3   | GHIJ  | NULL
----------------------
4   | MNOP  | 1
----------------------
5   | CDKL  | 2
----------------------
6   | QRST  | 3
----------------------
```

this should return:

```
Id  | Name  | ParentId 
----------------------
1   | ABCD  | NULL
----------------------
2   | EFZX  | NULL
----------------------
```

Edit2:
the first select returns the cities with matching names
the second select returns the cities with matching children
then merge the two results.

Comment: Add some test data and expected resultset.

Comment: please explain how you get that result. i can't figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can suggest solution with one select.
I have considered that you want result by parents and also by immediate descendants. So you should select all rows where name matches 'CD'

```
SELECT * FROM @cities
WHERE CHARINDEX(N'CD', Name) > 0
```

This will give you

```
1   ABCD    NULL
5   CDKL    2
6   CDKP    2
```

You want select only parents, that's why you need left join on parent to take rows where parent is 2

```
SELECT *  FROM @cities c1
LEFT JOIN @cities c2 ON c1.ParentId = c2.ID
WHERE CHARINDEX(N'CD', c1.Name) > 0
```

This returns

```
1   ABCD    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
5   CDKL    2       2       EFZX    NULL
6   CDKP    2       2       EFZX    NULL
```

Then you apply second where `and (c1.ParentId is NULL  OR (c1.ParentId IS NOT NULL AND c2.ParentId IS NULL))` to take parents and immediate descendants only.

```
 declare @cities table (Id int, Name NVARCHAR(MAX), ParentId INT null)

INSERT INTO @cities (Id, Name, ParentId) VALUES (1, 'ABCD', NULL)
INSERT INTO @cities (Id, Name, ParentId) VALUES (2, 'EFZX', NULL)
INSERT INTO @cities (Id, Name, ParentId) VALUES (3, 'GHIJ', NULL)
INSERT INTO @cities (Id, Name, ParentId) VALUES (4, 'MNOP', 1)
INSERT INTO @cities (Id, Name, ParentId) VALUES (5, 'CDKL', 2)
INSERT INTO @cities (Id, Name, ParentId) VALUES (6, 'CDKP', 2)




SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(c2.Id, c1.Id), ISNULL(c2.Name, c1.Name)  FROM @cities c1
LEFT JOIN @cities c2 ON c1.ParentId = c2.ID
WHERE CHARINDEX(N'CD', c1.Name) > 0 and (c1.ParentId is NULL  OR (c1.ParentId IS NOT NULL AND c2.ParentId IS NULL))
```

Comment: Thank you very much it's working as expected, but could you please explain a little? I'm not sure I get what's happening.
@Giorgi Nakeuri

Comment: sorry there was error. i have updated answer. please verify again..
i will update with explanation within 5 mins

Answer (score 0):

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
CREATE table #cities  (Id INT, Name VARCHAR(30), ParentId INT)


insert into #cities (Id, Name, ParentId) VALUES(1 , 'ABCD',NULL) 
insert into #cities (Id, Name, ParentId) VALUES(2 , 'EFZX',NULL) 
insert into #cities (Id, Name, ParentId) VALUES(3 , 'GHIJ',NULL) 
insert into #cities (Id, Name, ParentId) VALUES(4 , 'MNOP',1) 
insert into #cities (Id, Name, ParentId) VALUES(5 , 'CDKL',2) 
insert into #cities (Id, Name, ParentId) VALUES(6 , 'QRST',3)
```

**QUERY**

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    -- Select condition for parent
    SELECT Id, Name, ParentId,0 AS [LEVEL]
    FROM #cities --WHERE ParentId IS NULL --AND ID=1
    WHERE CHARINDEX(N'CD', Name) > 0 and ParentId is null 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT C1.*,C2.[LEVEL]+1 
    FROM #cities C1
    JOIN CTE C2 ON C1.ParentId=C2.Id
)
-- Since you get only parent and children, you can filter children here
SELECT * 
FROM CTE
WHERE CHARINDEX(N'CD', Name) > 0 
OPTION(MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: Updated. Check now @Star

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but your example returns only the first row (in my example data)

Comment: The** PARENTID IS Null** with the matching case **CD** have only one parent. And that parent doesn't have a child with **CD** as matching case @Star

Comment: OK, I'm sorry if the question was not clear but I need the parent if it matches or one of the child record matches

Comment: Oh. You need only parents? Does the child level can go upto n level or just the next level? @Star

Comment: Yes I need only parents, and there is only one level children